# Using PSEXEC to invoke a batch script on a remote machine won't launch Firefox

Tags: batch-file, windows-7, remote-access, xcopy, psexec

I am having the following issue:

Using PSEXEC, I remote into a machine to execute a batch script that is saved there, but the last line doesn't execute (it wont open Firefox .. the Firefox process shows up but the GUI doesn't launch). 
However, if I go to the remote machine and double-click the batch file it works just fine.

**Here is the command that I run locally:**

```
psexec -u USER -p PASSWORD \\REMOTE_SERVER -d cmd.exe /c "C:\Users\MY-REMOTE-MACHINE\Desktop\windows_setup.bat"
```

Here are the contents of that batch script:

```
taskkill /f /im "iexplore.exe" /t 
taskkill /f /im "chrome.exe" /t 
c:\Windows\SysWow64\TaskKill /f /im "iexplore.exe" /t 
c:\Windows\SysWow64\TaskKill /f /im "chrome.exe" /t 
start  "" "C:\Users\MY-REMOTE-MACHINE\AppData\Local\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"
```

- Note: I have also tried replacing the last line with `start firefox` ... same exact issue. It only works if I open the batch script directly from the target machine.

Comment: If you want launch a process in a particular user's session (so that it is visible to that user) you'll need to use the `-i` option to psexec.  You can psexec the `query user` command first to find the session number to use.

Comment: Thanks @HarryJohnston! 
I'm using a batch script to accomplish my task. Can you elaborate on using `query user` please?  Within a batch script I want to call `query user`, save the result to a variable, then use the variable in the following line to connect to a particular session (as described in my original question).

Comment: That should probably be a separate question, but you'd better try it yourself and/or check for existing answers first.  I imagine the best way to approach it would be using `for /F` so that may give you a starting point.